# Shorten my code

Tags: scala

My instinct says that the following code could be made shorter, but I cannot figure how. Can you help me?

```
def asGraphingFunction[A : Numeric, B : Numeric](f: PartialFunction[A, B]): Double => Double = {
  val (numericA, numericB) = (implicitly[Numeric[A]], implicitly[Numeric[B]])
  (x: Double) => {
    val xa: A = numericA.fromInt(x.toInt)
    if(f.isDefinedAt(xa))
      numericB.toDouble(f(xa))
    else
      0.0
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know Scala, but is there any particular reason why you want to make the code "shorter"? It seems fairly readable to me, isn't that more important than the number of lines of code?

Comment: @michael - they go hand in hand, see my answer to this

Answer (score 7):

Two tips here:

1. As you need the `Numeric` instances named, it's easier to just de-sugar the context bounds into implicit arguments
2. Use `PartialFunction#lift` to convert the `PartialFunction[A,B]` into an `A => Option[B]`

Then remove the boilerplate and... voila!

```
def asGraphingFunction[A, B](f: PartialFunction[A, B])
(implicit numA: Numeric[A], numB: Numeric[B]) =
  (x: Double) => f.lift(numA fromInt x.toInt) map (numB.toDouble) getOrElse 0.0
```

If you use a forward pipe operator (either from scalaz, or as defined [here](http://stevegilham.blogspot.com/2009/01/pipe-operator-in-scala.html)), then it can be made even more legible:

```
def asGraphingFunction[A, B](f: PartialFunction[A, B])
(implicit numA: Numeric[A], numB: Numeric[B]) =
  (x: Double) => (numA fromInt x.toInt) |> f.lift map (numB.toDouble) getOrElse 0.0
```

**Update**

As you're only converting ints/doubles, you don't actually need `Numeric` at all, you can do everything via `java.util.Number`, dropping the type params in the process:

```
def asGraphingFunction(f: PartialFunction[Number, _ <: Number]) =
  (x: Number) => f.lift(x.intValue) map (_.doubleValue) getOrElse 0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this?:

```
import scala.{ PartialFunction => PF }
def asGraphingFunction[A : Numeric, B : Numeric](f: PF[A, B]): Double => Double = {
  val pf1: PF[Double,A     ] = { case d => numericA.fromInt(d.toInt) }
  val pf2: PF[B     ,Double] = { case b => numericB.toDouble(b) }
  val pf3: PF[Double,Double] = { case _ => 0 }
  pf1 andThen f andThen pf2 orElse pf3
}
```

Not shorter but perhaps clearer?! Any comments?